# Calculating $\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} e^{ixt} e^{-i \omega t} dt$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

We know that Fourier Transform of $e^{ixt}$, where $x$ is a real parameter, $t\in \mathbb R$ is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ixt} e^{-i \omega t} dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ixt-i \omega t} dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i(x- \omega )t} dt=2 \pi \delta(x- \omega)$$
The result is the same if you consider the following integral?
$$\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} e^{ixt} e^{-i \omega t} dt$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\color{#00f}{\large\mbox{No}}.\quad\mbox{The last one is equal to}\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
2\,{\sin\left(\left[x - \omega\right]\pi\right) \over x - \omega}
& \mbox{if} & x \not= \omega
\\[3mm]
2\pi & \mbox{if} & x = \omega
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: costant "i" missing?

Comment: @Mark There is nothing missing. It's fine. The result is a $\large\tt\mbox{real number}$ since $\displaystyle\large\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp\left({\rm i}\left[x - \omega\right]t\right)\,{\rm d}t = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos\left(\left[x - \omega\right]t\right)\,{\rm d}t$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, for $x\neq \omega$ you have:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} e^{ixt} e^{-i \omega t} dt=2i\frac{e^{i\pi(x-\omega)}-e^{-i \pi(x-\omega)}}{2i(x-\omega)} =2i\frac{\sin(\pi (x-\omega))}{x-\omega} \neq 2 \pi \delta(x- \omega)$$

Comment: You have an extra $\Large{\rm i}$ before the symbol $\large\not=$.